# (Closed) C# Console autocomplete / suggest input, Code Improvement

Tags: c#, user-interface, input, console, usability

I am currently writing a C# console application. Part of it is, that the user needs to enter a fairly complex system name. To make it easier I wrote a function that uses a string[] keywords and auto completes the string the user is typing in - on the run.

The code is working and acts as expected, but I am curious how the code could be improved (e.g. usability, efficiency). Also, what functionalities are missing, which you'd expect?

Thank you for the feedback!

```
            if (Keywords.Length == 0)
                throw new Exception("No Keywords set!");

            bool searching          = true;                 // true while looking for the keyword
            Console.CursorVisible   = true;                 // To help users understand where they are typing
            string System           = "";                   // Initialization of output
            string suggestion       = Keywords[0];          // Initialization of default suggestion
            int toClear             = suggestion.Length;    // Get the length of the line that needs to be cleared

            while (searching)
            {
                Console.Write(new String(' ', toClear));    // Clear line
                Console.CursorLeft = 0;                     // Relocate cursor to line start
                Console.Write(System);                      // Write what has been written previously

                if(suggestion != "")                        // If there is a suggestion fitting the entered string,
                {                                           // complete the string in color and reset the cursor
                    int col = Console.CursorLeft;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                    Console.Write(suggestion.Substring(System.Length));
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.CursorLeft      = col;
                }

                string tempInput = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();

                if (tempInput.Equals("\r"))                 // Evaluate input:
                {                                           //  -> Enter
                    if (!suggestion.Equals(""))             //     Valid entry?
                    {
                        searching   = false;
                        System      = suggestion;           //      -> use suggestion
                    }
                }
                else if (tempInput.Equals("\b"))            // Deleting last sign
                {
                    if(System.Length>0)
                        System = System.Substring(0, System.Length - 1);
                }
                else                                        // Any other sign is added to the string
                    System      += tempInput;

                // Set length to clear, if suggestion == "", the system string length needs to be cleared
                toClear = (System.Length>suggestion.Length) ? System.Length : suggestion.Length;

                // Reset suggestion. If no match is found, suggestion remains empty
                suggestion = "";

                // Check keywords for suggestion
                for(int i= 0; i<Keywords.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (Keywords[i].StartsWith(System))
                    {
                        suggestion = Keywords[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // reset cursor visibility
            Console.CursorVisible = false;

            return System;
```

Comment: Post what you have (as a complete program) to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Improvements to working code isn't really the purpose of SO.

Comment: thanks @BrootsWaymb I wasn't aware of that page yet. I will move the question there

Comment: This question has been moved to [Codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201578/c-console-autocomplete-suggest-input-code-improvement). Please comment there about the subject.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question has been moved to codereview already.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen As far as I can see I am not able to add a "[closed]" tag to the question, I can not delete it, since someone answered it and according to this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96281/how-to-close-a-question-in-stackoverflow-com) the way to go would be to accept an answer which I already did. If you can let me know how to officially close a question I'd be thankful.

Comment: Just let the voting system work, no need to do anything else, enough people will vote to close it, or they won't. Not a big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Do not raise reserved exception types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2201-do-not-raise-reserved-exception-types)

   ```
   if (Keywords.Length == 0)
       throw new Exception("No Keywords set!");
   ```

   Instead use

   ```
   if (Keywords.Length == 0)
       throw new ArgumentException(nameof(Keywords), "No Keywords set!");
   ```
2. I would not use `System` as a variable name. `System` is a very common namespace.
3. Not sure is it is due to formatting, but the tabs between assignments are not consistent and make the code harder to read
4. <s>You calculate the length to clear, but never use it</s>

   // Set length to clear, if suggestion == "", the system string length needs to be cleared
   toClear = (System.Length>suggestion.Length) ? System.Length : suggestion.Length;

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I included your changes and am moving the question to Code Review, since that is the place where it belongs.

About the toClear, I am using it when the while-loop restarts